# PyCurl alternative, a pythonic wrapper for libcurl?

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl

PycURL is a thin wrapper around  the C libcurl API, I wonder if there's any more pythonic wrapper for libcurl which supports `CurlMulti` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most bindings made for C libraries, it is clever to make a very thin layer on top of it to offer the most of it.

This said, it generally makes sense to wrap that binding itself then to offer more higher level features and more language-specific ways to do things, rather than to write yet another binding.

So no, I don't know of any such wrapper but I would advice that such a wrapper would be made on top of pycurl rather than on top of libcurl directly!